# 2 if statement with 1 else destroying a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, nested

here my Python Code is

```
while True:
    a = int(input("enter a digit"))
    if a < 10:
        print("digit is less than 10")
    if a < 50 and a > 10:
        print("digit is more than 10")
    else:
        print("error")
```

so my doubt is when i run this program for (a < 10) then it will show the correct output with respected to it's if statement but it will also give the output of else statement as well with if. But with the if condition mentioned in second phrase which is (a<50 and a > 10), the output is only "digit is more than 10" which is correct but why there is an extra output of else,when value is less than 10 .

Comment: Use `if/elif/else`. What should happen if `a == 10`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want all your `if` statements to be part of the same `if..else` block, then you should do:

```
while True:
    a = int(input("enter a digit"))
    if a < 10:
        print("digit is less than 10")
    elif a < 50 and a > 10:
        print("digit is more than 10")
    else:
        print("error")
```

**Explanation:**

Your current code has two diferent `if..else` blocks:

```
a = int(input("enter a digit"))
if a < 10:
    print("digit is less than 10")


if a < 50 and a > 10:
    print("digit is more than 10")
else:
    print("error")
```

So if `a<10`, it will print `"digit is less than 10"`. Then that `if` block ends, and your code enters the second `if` block. Since `a` is not between `10` and `50`, it will enter the `else` statement and print `"error"`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is really helpful for me

Comment: You're welcome @Priyanshu, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider upvoting it and accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have two `if` statements you need an `elif`

```
 if a < 10:
     print("digit is less than 10")
 elif a < 50 and a > 10:
     print("digit is more than 10")
 else:
     print("error")
```

output:

```
enter a digit1
digit is less than 10
enter a digit50
error
enter a digit49
digit is more than 10
enter a digit
enter a digit90
error
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Happening Because in Sequential Code Runs Like

> If Statememt(a < 10)
>
> If else Statement(a > 10 and a < 50)

In Case of `a < 10`:

> if Statment `a<10` Prints
>
> If statment `10 < a < 50`:(false) so `else` Print Executes

Answer (score 0):

In these situations where you need more statements, you need to use the elif statement.
This is the solution:
        while True:
        a = int(input("enter a digit"))
             if a < 10:
                print("digit is less than 10")
             elif a < 50 and a > 10:
                print("digit is more than 10")
             else:
                print("error")